# Java logging in LibreOffice extension

Tags: java, logging, libreoffice

I have compiled a LibreOffice extension and generated an OXT file which i added to LibreOffice.

Is there any way I can see all the java logging that happens in this extension while testing it live in LibreOffice?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add your own logging. i have successfully used log4j with my java LO extension. just add the log4j.xml file to the generated LO extension jar. assumimg your log4j.xml file it at top level of your LO generated jar and that you added log4j.jar to your project classpath before compiling and generating the extension jar. then in your main class entry for LO java extension in initialize() method you can configure your log4j with following code:

```
 // com.sun.star.lang.XInitialization:
/**
 *
 * @param object
 * @throws com.sun.star.uno.Exception
 */
@Override
public void initialize(Object[] object)
        throws com.sun.star.uno.Exception {
   //some init stuff here

    //initialize log4j
    DOMConfigurator.configure(getClass().getResource("log4j.xml"));
    _logger = Logger.getLogger(YourExtensionClassName.class);



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Good old school System.out.println() also works, at least in LibreOffice debug (nightly) build. I run LO from command line and see stdout in console. I was using LO on Linux box.